# npm build local dependencies in order

Tags: docker, npm, build

I am using npm to manage dependencies for my Typescript project. This project references a handful of other, local npm modules (e.g. using `npm install ../path_to_package`).

All works fine locally but I would like to build a docker image for my main project. This involves copying each local package to the docker build context and building them all. Currently, I copy each required package:

```
COPY packages/package_1/ ./packages/package_1/
COPY packages/package_2/ ./packages/package_2/
COPY packages/package_3/ ./packages/package_3/
COPY main_project/ ./main_project/
```

and then build them in the order that they are needed (say packge_1 depends on package_2, package_2 must be built, then package_1):

```
RUN cd packages/package_2 && npm install && npm run build && cd ../ \
 && cd packages/package_1 && npm install && npm run build && cd ../ \
 && cd packages/package_3 && npm install && npm run build && cd ../ \
 && cd main_project && npm install && npm run build
```

This is obviously very inconvenient to have to manually check the dependency tree of `main_project` to then build the packages in order, especially when I create and install new local packages. Is there a way to, based on main_project's package.json for example (or package-lock.json) automatically copy and build the dependencies in order, then build the main project?